# Customizing full screen intent notifications android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, background-service, foreground-service

*Project Target API 30 Android 10, Min API 19 KitKat*

I am creating a parental control app where parents can restrict certain apps.
I have a foreground service where I would I ideally trigger an activity-like notification from the service that would envelop the user's entire screen or take them to the home screen.
I have learned that starting activities, including going to the home screen, is no longer possible under normal circumstances as of API 29. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

After reading the documentation it seems creating a full screen intent notification is the most highly recommended workaround to the activity restriction.

I am currently working with the following code for my full screen intent notification:

```
                    Intent blockedIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(), BlockedItemReceiver.class);
                    blockedIntent.putExtra("currentApp", restrictedApp.name);
                    PendingIntent pendingBlockedIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(App.getContext(), 50, blockedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder blockedNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(App.getContext(), CHANNEL_BLOCKED_FROM_ITEM)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_lock_24)
                                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                    .setContentTitle(restrictedApp.packageName + " was Blocked!")
                                    .setContentText(restrictedApp.name + " will be available again DAY at TIME")
                                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                                    .setFullScreenIntent(pendingBlockedIntent, true);


                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(5, blockedNotificationBuilder.build());
```

I looked at some documentation for customizing notifications, but the information I found does not have a full screen intent notification example, and when I attempt to add the methods in the documentation example for NotificationCompat.Builder such as setCustomContentView() with custom layouts, my notification fails to appear without an error message.
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification
Besides, I do not want a collapsed and expanded version of my notification as the example in the link has, just one full screen view.

**TLDR; I want a notification that always engulfs the screen until the user presses a button on the notification to dismiss it. How can I further customize my full screen intent notification to truly take up the full screen? Ideally with a layout. If I must have a collapsed version of my notification, I don't want the user to ever see it, because I always want my notification to engulf the screen while it's showing.**

There are existing apps such as AppBlock that have found a workaround to launching an activity-like thing from a foreground service that takes up the full screen, so what I am trying to do is possible even if the specific question I'm asking won't lead me to that result. Please suggest another way of accomplishing what I am after if what I am asking to do in my question is "impossible". What I generally want to do is certainly possible.